# Add the same control to a toolbox multiple times with different properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a custom control that inherits from Label, and implements various additional properties. At run-time I populate a custom toolbox with *n* number ToolboxItems where the type is of my custom control; the DisplayName property for each item is different based on run-time conditions.  When I drag and drop any of the items to the design surface, they all have the same default properties, and that is what I am trying to solve.  Based on the aforementioned run-time conditions, I need to set the additional properties that I have implemented and each item would have different property values.

An easy way to visualize this is to think about Crystal Reports or the Report Designer in Visual Studio: the datasource of a report contains *n* number of fields which are all basically the same control when they are dropped onto the report, they just have different default properties when they hit the design surface.

Thanks for any help anyone might be able to provide!

Per the comment below:

A ToolboxItem is initialized like this:

```
 container.Add(new ToolboxItem(typeof(myType)));
```

A concrete initialization is not passed in (obviously), otherwise this would be a trivial matter.

Comment: So set those additional properties before you add the controls to your toolbox?!  What's the specific issue here?  Your dialog makes it sounds like you have most of this implemented already.  What is keeping you from doing exactly what you described?

Comment: I have added an explanation, but it is because a ToolboxItem does not take a concrete class, it takes a type ala: container.Add(new ToolboxItem(typeof(myType)));

Comment: You could externally **associate** each ToolBoxItem() with your class by using a **Dictionary<ToolBoxItem, YourClassInstanceTypeHere>**?